# Charts: Disabling/Hiding the first node point in Line chart

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

I successfully drawn a multiline chart using Charts library in Swift. However there is a minor customisation I need. Looking up the documentation I haven't found anything relative in the properties of datasets and line chart.

Here's slice of screenshot from my multiline chart.

[image]

My requirement is all the lines should start from Y-Axis but the first nodal point which is on Left axis shouldn't have a circle on it e.g the (0, 30) point.

Remaining all the nodal points must have a circle on them as shown in the image. Is any property out there in any class which toggles off the first nodal point or any other alternate customization I can do to achieve this?

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle with some raw data.